# How to make wait_for wait for everybody's reaction?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
embed = discord.Embed(title = "Currently Playing", colour = discord.Colour.blue())
embed.add_field(name = "Song", value = title, inline = False)
embed.add_field(name = "Length", value = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds = length)), inline = False)
embed.add_field(name = "Link", value = url, inline = False)
msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
await msg.add_reaction("\u23F8")
await msg.add_reaction("\u25B6")
await msg.add_reaction("\u23F9")
while True:
  try:
    reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", check=lambda reaction, user: user.id == ctx.author.id and reaction.message.id == msg.id and reaction.emoji in ["\u23F8", "\u25B6", "\u23F9"], timeout = length)
  
  except asyncio.TimeoutError:
    return await msg.clear_reactions()
      
  async def process():
    if reaction.emoji == "\u23F8":
      await msg.remove_reaction(reaction.emoji, ctx.author)
      ctx.voice_client.pause()
    elif reaction.emoji == "\u25B6":
      await msg.remove_reaction(reaction.emoji, ctx.author)
      ctx.voice_client.resume()
    elif reaction.emoji == "\u23F9":
      await msg.remove_reaction(reaction.emoji, ctx.author)
      ctx.voice_client.stop()

  asyncio.create_task(process())
```

Here I have a snippet of code from a play command, its supposed to send a message after a song is requested, the message has reactions that pause, play or stop when reacted to by a user. Additionally the bot automatically deletes the reaction immediately after it is hit so that the reactions can be used more than once by the same user.

Currently the code works well, the only problem is the reactions only respond to the person that originally invoked the play command and not anyone else in the server. The cause of this is evident, its due to the `user: user.id == ctx.author.id` in the wait_for causing it to only wait for reactions from the author, and the `await msg.remove_reaction(reaction.emoji, ctx.author)` which will cause it to only remove reactions added by the author. When I try to remove the `user: user.id == ctx.author.id` the play command stops working entirely. The remove_reaction requires a member argument, when I try to replace ctx.author with user while the `user: user.id == ctx.author.id` is removed it does the same thing, and with the `user: user.id == ctx.author.id` it has no effect as user is defined as author. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest against trying to remove reactions, it's something that's very easy to get your bot rate limited. Just let them react. If you must find a way, I can definitely write you an answer for that.

Comment: The reason I want to remove reactions is so a user doesn’t have to undo and click again to use a reaction the second time. For example if you want to pause you hit the reaction, then you play, but you need to pause again you have to click the play reaction twice. It’s a little bothersome so I want to find a way to fix it.

Comment: Perhaps I misread your question, you want your bot's music commands to respond to everyone so that everyone can react and trigger the command?

Comment: In that case, simply remove `user.id == ctx.author.id` and use `await msg.remove_reaction(reaction.emoji, user)` instead of `ctx.author`.

Comment: Yes, when doing it I get this weird bug where at times the songs play and everything works, and at times I request a song and the first second plays and then its stops. Strangely, I dont get an error and I can play another song after it, but the bug comes up often. I've tested it out with the original code that only allows the author to react and everything works fine. I can provide the code for the whole command if you want to look deeper.

Comment: You should add `not user.bot` to your check, it sounds like your wait_for check may be processing the bot's own reaction which sometimes happens due to latency.